# Pusher with Laravel Application along Queue Jobs working with QUEUE_DRIVER set to databse in env file instead sync

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, pusher, laravel-queue

Laravel Version: 5.6

Can I use pusher for a Laravel web application with QUEUE_DRIVER option set to "database" in env file?

Currently, there are Queue Jobs running with the queue connection set to "database" in env file.

I have to implement the pusher for notifications, but the queue driver connection setting is conflicting with the pusher settings.

I do not know why pusher needs to use QUEUE_DRIVER=sync in env file to work properly. I can not set it to sync because queue jobs are running with connection set to "database."

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure the notifications aren't being sent with Pusher because the queued jobs are sitting idle in the database and have not been ran yet to dispatch the notifications?

Comment: @bradforbes notifications gets send out when QUEUE_DRIVER is set to sync in env file, when it's set to database, notifications queue remains idle in jobs table, and do not get processed. While other jobs just works fine meanwhile

Comment: OK, maybe it's not relevant, but I'm just wondering if you ran the queue with `php artisan queue:work`, do the notifications get sent when the jobs process?

Comment: Now both queue and pusher are working fine. I am not sure if it's the correct way? I set QUEUE_DRIVER=sync in env, and pusher notifications are working fine without disturbing queues processes. On the other side I have specified queue connection to database [onConnection('database');] where I dispatch queue jobs.

Answer (score 1):

In the event class of Pusher, you can try use ***implements ShouldBroadcastNow***

> ShouldBroadcastNow will use the 'sync' connection driver for the Queue, which means that it will be fired immediately.
>
> It's not necessarely the case when using ShouldBroadcast. But if no connection is specified in your event class it should use the default Queue configuration which is sync as well. So except if you changed this configuration in the queue.php config file, I think that it should behave the same by default.

It works for me

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/events-shouldbroadcastnow-vs-shouldbroadcast
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdmG3.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858415)

Comment: ok, i have just fixed it @SemihArslanoglu